# How to programatically change the mat-button-toggle-group state

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the MatButtonToogleGroup state with a confirmation dialog, but I can't find a way to prevent the default behavior (only if I change back to the previous state on Cancel).

HTML file:

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group [value]="value" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="StatusType.Open">
    Open
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="StatusType.Closed">
    Closed
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

TS file:

```ts
@Input() value: StatusType;
@Output() statusChange = new EventEmitter<StatusType>();

onChange(event: MatButtonToggleChange): void {
   const newValue = event.value;

    if (newValue === StatusType.Open) {
      this.statusChange.emit(value);

      return;
    }

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        title: 'Confirm status change',
        message: 'Are you sure?',
      }
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        filter((result) => !!result)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.statusChange.emit(newValue);
      });
}
```

And what I actually need is to add an `event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the `onChange` function, but the `MatButtonToggleChange` event does not have the `preventDefault()` method because behind the scenes it implements the `ControlValueAccessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try to do is to use `ngModel` instead. You can add a clickListener on the group or all the toggle buttons, and then open the dialog. After the user confirms the dialog, you can set the model.

**HTML File**

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="StatusType.Open" (click)="onClick($event)">
    Open
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="StatusType.Closed" (click)="onClick($event)">
    Closed
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

**TS File**

```ts
  onClick(event: any): void {
    const newValue = event.value;

    if (newValue === StatusType.Open) {
      this.statusChange.emit(value);

      return;
    }

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        title: 'Confirm status change',
        message: 'Are you sure?',
      }
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        filter((result) => !!result)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.statusChange.emit(newValue);
      });
  }
```

Here's a Stackblitz with a minimal example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layjkm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-appearance-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

This would need a reassignment to the internal state of the event of type **MatButtonToggleChange** emitted by the toggle component. Usage of **ngModel** is needed on the group to set a default selection. You can go through all the properties of the event emitted and use it.

*These kind of hacks should be considered as the last resort and better UX solutions or component choice will solve the root cause of problem better*

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group color="primary" (change)="changeItem($event)"
            [ngModel]="selectedItem">
            <mat-button-toggle [checked]="selectedItem.id === item.id" [value]="item" color="primary"
                *ngFor="let item of items">
                {{ item.label }}
            </mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

```
changeItem(event: MatButtonToggleChange): void {
      const clickedOption = event.source.value;
      if (!confirm('Are you sure to change ?')) {
          event.source.buttonToggleGroup.value = this.selectedItem
      } else {
          this.selectedItem = event.source.buttonToggleGroup.value;
      }
}
```

Here is the stackblitz example  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjn6ga-yxwytq?file=main.ts. Works fine with recent versions like Angular 13 too.